# Sum all positive values as col1 and all negative values as col2 and group by name SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Why do I get nothing back when use where `col < 0`?

table

```
name  transactions
A        100    
A        -50 
A         50      
B        200   
B       -100
C        250  
C       -150 
C        100
```

I want to write a query that gives the sum of positive transactions as IN and sum of negative transactions as OUT  for each name?

I tried:

```
Select name, sum(transactions > 0)as IN, sum(transactions < 0)as OUT 
From table
Group by name;
```

Expected table:

```
name    IN    OUT
A       150   50
B       200   100
C       350   150
```

OR

Expected table:

```
name    IN    OUT
A       150   -50
B       200   -100
C       350   -150
```

Comment: `Sum (case when ... then ...)`

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

you  could use a Case when

```
select  name
      , sum(case when transactions >= 0  then transactions else 0 end) `IN` 
      , sum(case when transactions < 0  then transactions else 0 end)  `OUT` 
from table
group by name
```

or IF()

```
select  name
      , sum(if( transactions >= 0, transactions,  0)) `IN` 
      , sum(if( transactions < 0, transactions,  0))  `OUT` 
from table
group by name
```

*your code  `sum(transactions > 0)`  return just the boolean evaluation so return just 0 or 1 and the related  sum  ..*